# How do I convert this javascript date picker date to milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, datetime-conversion

I need to do a conditional where I test whether the date from a date picker has passed already. I need to compare it to todays date using Date.now(); which returns milliseconds.

when I my log date picker date from my object - listOfEventsObject[i].date - it prints in this form:

```
 **2017-08-15** . 

while date.now() outputs this: **1503904013430**
```

how can I convert the date picker date in order to see if the time has passed?

**UPDATE** It does not work to use getTime(); 
when I use getTime(); it removes everything from the array. I only need passed dates left out of the array.

my code:

```
    function getPostsSuccess (listOfEventsObject){ /*callback which passes 
                                                             array to loop*/

        for (var i in listOfEventsObject) {

                if(listOfEventsObject[i].date.getTime() < Date.now()){

                       this.listOfEvents.push(listOfEventsObject[i]);

}//close if

                }//close loop



            }//close callback
```

Comment: `new Date('2017-08-15').getTime()`

Comment: You don't even need *getTime*: `new Date('2017-08-15') < Date.now()`, or if *listOfEventsObject[i].date* returns a Date object, `listOfEventsObject[i].date < Date.now()`.

Comment: Datepicker is implemented in such a twisted manner in javascript, any question regarding that is a boon to humankind.. Upvoting this question..

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `.getTime()` method of the date object to get milliseconds that can be compared to `Date.now()`.

```js
var before = new Date(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

var now = Date.now();

var after = new Date(2100, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

console.log("before is before now: %s", before.getTime() < now);

console.log("after is after now: %s", after.getTime() > now);
```

Comment: please see my updates

Comment: @Spilot: There's not enough information in your question to know why that would be.

Comment: I'm not sure what else I can include. If anyone else has suggestions I still need them.

Comment: We would need to see your data. Other than that, you'll need to solve this using typical debugging measure, which would at least include logging your values using `console.log()` to get a visual indication of why the comparisons are not giving the expected result.

Comment: There is no need for *getTime*, the less than operator coerces the Date to number.

Comment: @RobG: True, it'll call its `.valueOf()` method, which gives the same data.